# returning boolean values from functions

Tags: javascript, function, boolean

I'm making a game that starts of with 15-30 stones in a pile, and both the user and computer take stones until the last stone is taken. However, I need a function to determine whether the amount of stones the user take is valid, meaning it is less than or equal to 3 and greater than 0. So my function is supposed to return either true or false, but when I enter "2", it returns false. Here's the code invovled:

```
var valid = validEntry(stones, stonesTaken);

function validEntry(stones, stonesTaken) {
    if (stones >= stonesTaken) {
        if(stonesTaken <= 3 && stonesTaken > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

P.S.-- Whenever the stones goes under three, the player nor the computer can take more stones than are available, which is why the first if statement is there.

Comment: When you enter 2 for stones taken what is the value of stones?  I'm guessing your first conditional fails

Comment: Looks valid here: http://jsfiddle.net/2gCD9/

Comment: In case JSFiddle doesn't work (it didn't for me when I tried to open my own link). http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxeKp it works.

Comment: You should perhaps `parseInt()` on both and then all you need is `stonesTaken <= 3`.

Comment: @KevinBowersox the value of stones was 24, at the beginning of the game, it never goes under 15.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're comparing strings:

```
"19" >= "2" // false
```

You have to cast at least one variable into an integer, assuming they're both strings:

```
stones = parseInt(stones, 10);
stonesTaken = parseInt(stonesTaken, 10);
```

Comment: earlier in the code i had written:
`var stonesTaken = document.getElementById("userTake").value * 1;`
which i thought would force the string into an integer

Comment: Well, `validEntry(24, 2)` gives `true` for me, so something else must be off.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass integer values or just use `parseInt()` as @Jared Farrish mentioned in comments.

```
function validEntry(stones, stonesTaken) {
    stones = parseInt(stones);
    stonesTaken = parseInt(stonesTaken);
    if (stones >= stonesTaken) {
        if(stonesTaken <= 3 && stonesTaken > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```